# Converter SQL em DQL

Tags: php, doctrine-2

Opa a todos, preciso converter um SQL em DQL do Doctrine 2 se alguem poder me ajudar obrigado.

```
SELECT 
produtos.id, 
produtos.categoria_id, 
produtos.nome, 
produtos.descricao, 
produtos.valor, 
(SELECT group_concat(nome) 
FROM tags 
INNER JOIN produtos_tags ON rodutos_tags.tag_id = tags.id 
WHERE produtos.id= produtos_tags.produto_id) as teste 
FROM produtos 
INNER JOIN categorias ON produtos.categoria_id = categorias.id 
INNER JOIN produtos_tags ON produtos_tags.produto_id = produtos.id 
INNER JOIN tags ON produtos_tags.tag_id = tags.id 
GROUP BY produto_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para conseguir montar uma DQL, é necessário saber a organização das entidades da sua aplicação e o relacionamento entre elas – se é `OneToMany`, `ManyToMany`, `ManyToOne` ou `OneToOne`. Vou sugerir uma resposta mas é provável que eu esteja errado. Nesse caso, tente providenciar os dados que falei acima. :)

Veja se serve:

```
SELECT 
    p.id, 
    p.categoria, 
    p.nome, 
    p.descricao, 
    p.valor, 
    (
        SELECT group_concat(t.nome) 
        FROM Tags t2
        JOIN t.produtos p2
        WHERE p2.id = p.id
    ) as teste 
FROM Produto p
JOIN p.categorias c
JOIN p.tags t
GROUP BY p.id
```